# HTML structure problem with a vuetify v-data-table

Tags: html, css, datatable, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I use NuxtJS and Vuetify.

I made a table with "v-data-table".
I want to add some style to some cells in this table and in particular, put a separation between some cells.

So I use "template" and v-slot inside the data-table.
Here is what my code looks like:

```
<v-data-table
                    v-model="selected"
                    :single-select="false"
                    item-key="id"
                    show-select
                    :headers="headers"
                    :items="dossiers"
                    :options.sync="options"
                    :server-items-length="totalDossiers"
                    :loading="loading"
                    :search="searchDossiers"
                    :items-per-page="20"
                    :footer-props="{ 'items-per-page-options': items_per_page }"
                    class="elevation-4 table-cursor"
                    @click:row="goDossier"
                >
                    <template v-slot:[`item.ville`]="{ item }">
                        <td
                            class="array-right-border d-flex align-center justify-center"
                        >
                            {{ item.ville }}
                        </td>
                    </template>
                </v-data-table>


<style>
.array-right-border {
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.205);
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

It works pretty much BUT when I look in the HTML inspector I see that I'm creating a "td" tag in the base "td" tag of the vuetify table. Which is not very clean and causes an offset problem regarding the border. So I would have to delete that first  or I could place my "array-right-border" class on the first .
Any ideas?

[html inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtAfF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to place a new `<td>` tag in `item.<name>` slot.

Your static CSS classes can be placed in `cellClass` attribute of headers object for a specific column:

```js
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  ...
>
  <template v-slot:[`item.ville`]="{ item }">
    {{ item.ville }}
  </template>
</v-data-table>

...

data () {
  return {
    headers: [
      {
        value: 'ville', 
        cellClass: 'array-right-border d-flex align-center justify-center' 
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Take a look at Calories column [in this CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/NWYVJaq).

Comment: Thank you, I did not know cellClass, I will be able to review my tables